# Which useEffect will be called after every Render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-effect, react-functional-component

I'm a beginner in React and stuck with some problem. I have several queries regarding this code.

1. Which UseEffect will be called after every render?
2. Why and How console.log() is called 13 times ?(Please find the screenshot below)
3. Why the fetched data is not shown in browser until I type something in the search bar?

   App.js

   ```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";

    function App() {
      const [monster, setMonster] = useState([]);
      const [searchName, setName] = useState("");
      const [filteredMonster, setFilter] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
         async function fetchData() {
           await axios.get(
              "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
           ).then((resp)=>{
              setMonster(resp.data);
           })
           console.log(monster);
         }

         fetchData();
      }, []);

      useEffect(()=>{
         const mons = monster;
         setFilter(mons.filter(mon =>
            mon.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchName.toLowerCase())
         ));
      }, [searchName]);

      function changeName(event) {
         setName(event.target.value);
      }

      console.log(monster);

      const cunter = useRef(0);
      return (
         <div className="App">
            <form>
               <input
                  type="search"
                  name="searchName"
                  value={searchName}
                  onChange={changeName}
               />
            </form>

           {cunter.current++}

            {filteredMonster&&filteredMonster.map((item, index) => (
               <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}

            {monster&&!filteredMonster&&monster.map((item, index) => (
               <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
             ))}
         </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
   ```

[image: App]

[image: Cunter]

Answer (score 0):

try this please. fetchData() will run only 1, searchName will run as many times you type on the screen.

TIP: To prevent this. add a timeoutdelay after user finishes typing to only render once instead of N times user presses a keyboard key.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

function App() {
    const [monster, setMonster] = useState([]);
    const [searchName, setName] = useState("");
    const [filteredMonster, setFilter] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            await axios.get(URL).then((resp) => {
                setMonster(resp.data);
            })
            console.log(monster);
        }

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (monster.length > 0) {
            const filter = mons.filter(({name}) =>
                name.toLowerCase().includes(searchName.toLowerCase()));
            setFilter(filter);
        }

    }, [searchName]);

    function changeName(event) {
        setName(event.target.value);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(monster));

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form>
                <input
                    type="search"
                    name="searchName"
                    value={searchName}
                    onKeyUp={(e) => changeName(e)}
                />
            </form>

            {monster.length > 0 &&
                <div>{JSON.stringify(monster)}</div>
            }

            {filteredMonster && filteredMonster.map((item, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}

            {monster && !filteredMonster && monster.map((item, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is using Reducer, removes the use of state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'FETCH_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                monster: action.monster,
                name: "",
            }
        case 'SEARCH_MONSTER':
            return {
                ...state,
                name: action.name,
            }
        case 'FILTER_MONSTER':
            const filter = state.monster.filter(({name}) =>
                name.toLowerCase().includes(searchName.toLowerCase()));
            return {
                ...state,
                filteredMonster: filter,
                name: state.name,
            }
    }
};

function App() {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
        monster: [],
        filteredMonster: [],
        name: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            await axios.get(URL).then((resp) => {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_DATA', monster: resp.data});
            })
            console.log(monster);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (monster.length > 0)  dispatch({ type: 'FILTER_MONSTER'});
    }, [stat.name]);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(monster));

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form>
                <input
                    type="search"
                    name="searchName"
                    value={state.name}
                    onKeyUp={(e) => dispatch({ type: 'SEARCH_MONSTER', name: e.target.value })}
                />
            </form>

            {state.monster.length > 0 &&
                <div>{JSON.stringify(monster)}</div>
            }

            {state.filteredMonster && state.filteredMonster.map((item, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}

            {state.monster && !state.filteredMonster && monster.map((item, index) => (
                <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Which UseEffect will be called after every render?**

**Ans:** According to the [react official doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)  `useEffect` does care about 3 lifecycle method namely `componentDidMount` `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`. So no matter what how many `useEffect` you have, all the effect hooks will execute when componentMount for the first time. But `useEffect` will execute further, only when it's dependency get updates else it will ignore

**2. Why and How console.log() is called 13 times?**

**Ans:** I tried to reproduce 13 times rerendering but I am not able to do so. But yes it's rerendering multiple times because in the 2nd `useEffect` on every Keystore the state is updating and because of that component is rerendering several times.

its happening something like this

changeName() → setName() → useEffect() → setFilter() → (on every keystore repeating same step) → ...loop

you can try `debounce` or `throttling` which can help you to avoid continuous Keystore hit by which no of rerendering can drastically reduce

*Instead of using **console.log**, there is a hack to know the number of rerendering*

declare the below code in the component

```
const cunter = useRef(0);
```

and then in the return block add `{cunter.current++}` by this you can see how many times your component is actually rerendering

**3. Why the fetched data is not shown in the browser until I type something in the search bar?**

This is because in your condition your checking `!filteredMonster` where `filteredMonster` is an array and `!filteredMonster` will return always `false` instead try Array `length` properties

`filteredMonster.length  === 0`

```
{monster && !filteredMonster && monster.map((item, index) => (
     <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
))}

{(monster && filteredMonster.length === 0) && monster.map((item, index) => (
         <p key={index}>{item.name}</p>
))}
```

Comment: How without any keystrokes the component gets rendered 4 times? Please find the screenshot above.

Comment: When I tried to solve the mystery of multiple rerendering I found this magic is done by `React.StrictMode`. 

**How I got to know this**. Created a simple component that just returns only one `h1` without `React.StrictMode`and observed it **rendered only once** and then, Enabled `React.StrictMode` in the same component by which it **rendered twice**

Why it's rendering twice then [this post gave me the ans](https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/)

Comment: So we know that react rerenders every time when the state gets updated.

Why rendering 4 times?
Again I had different observations. without `strictMode` a component rendered `thrice`  (initialRender + useEffect which update `setMonster` + `useEffect` which update `setFilter`). But by enabling `strictMode` in the same codebase it rendered `6 times` for which I answered in the previous comment with a post link